# wxWidgets installation lacks setup.h file. Why?

Tags: linux, python, opensuse, c

I've just upgraded my machine to OpenSuSE Leap 15.5. In order to install a Python-based app named DisplayCAL, I need to setup the recent version of Python, wxWidgets, and the wxPython bindings. Python 3.11 is already on board:

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  rpm -q python311-base
python311-base-3.11.2-150400.9.5.6.x86_64
```

…and wxWidgets, too:

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  rpm -qa | grep wxWidgets
wxWidgets-3_2-devel-3.1.5-150400.1.7.x86_64
```

But unfortunately, `pip` refuses to install `wxPython`…

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  pip install wxPython --verbose
```

…due to a missing `wx/setup.h` file:

```
  In file included from ../../../../ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/defs.h:45:0,
                   from ../../../../ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/wx.h:14,
                   from ../../../../wx/include/wxPython/wxpy_api.h:41,
                   from ../../../../sip/cpp/sipAPI_core.h:22068,
                   from ../../../../sip/cpp/sip_corewxZoomGestureEvent.cpp:10:
  ../../../../ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/platform.h:159:10: fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory.
   #include "wx/setup.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
```

Well yeah, I've found `platform.h` in `/usr/include/wx-3.1/wx` (and it does contain an include directive in line 159, so it must be the file I've been looking for), but I can't find no `setup.h` in this folder. Apparently it's not part of the `wxWidgets-3_2-devel` package.

Where can I get the missing `setup.h`?

**UPDATE:** [The corresponding page in the pkgs.org reference](https://opensuse.pkgs.org/15.3/opensuse-oss-x86_64/wxWidgets-3_2-devel-3.1.1.g3-bp153.1.37.s390x.rpm.html) told me that there is a file named `/usr/lib64/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1/wx/setup.h`, which is part of the `wxWidgets-3_2-devel` package. **But:** Linking this file to `/usr/include/wx-3.1/wx` does NOT help. Apparently, the `platform.h` (which raises the error) is not the one situated under `/usr/include/wx-3.1/wx`, but I can't find such a header file anywhere on my machine! Is the pip build process using some shadow files invisible to the normal user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After skimming through [a Github issue](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2422), I found out that the necessary header files come with the tarball downloaded from PyPi, so I had to open the tarball and then copy the `/ext/include/wx/setup_inc.h` file into `setup.h` in the same folder.